# Smart guide snapping not accurate

Tags: adobe-illustrator, snapping, isometric

I have setup a isometric grid by creating smart guider rotated 120 degrees and working with the intersect points. When I'm working on vertex level this works great but when I want to group my object and "put it aside" or even move it a couple of "tiles" it does not snap correctly. I have tried to increase DPI but this does not give better results.

Is this a known problem and is there a fix or solution for this? I need to be very precise and I really need a grid to work faster is Illustrator the right tool for the job?

Comment: There is no DPI setting in illustrator! Always use the direct selection tool and make sure you drag from a vertex as it snaps to your currsor position. suggest you disable alignment guides. Yes this is annoying but workable. Theres always autocad but it has same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to disalign objects with the pixel grid. In the transform window (Window > Transform) You will see a checkbox labeled 'align to pixel grid'. Uncheck it.

To avoid it in the future when you begin a new document - go into the same dialog window and in the right hand corner menu of that transform window uncheck "new objects align to pixel grid"

[image: Align to Pixel Grid]

Comment: It's checked but grayed out so I cannot uncheck it.

Comment: There is a saying stupid question do not exist.. I had to select an object obviously. And this actually worked out. I mark this one for the answer, for the bottom options to show I had to select `Show option` in the top right preferences panel of the transform window too.

Answer (score 2):

OPEN "Windows">"transform". There will three checkmarks at the very bottom of that window. I'm not sure what the last check box is called in english but unchecking it usually solves that problem. I think its called "Align to Pixel grid".

Answer (score 0):

Smart guides can be more of a nuisance than anything, but for this case there is a solution. Zoom way in, that makes the guides less "snappy".